# Loggedin pages after authintification

Tags: django

I am learning django by myself and created mini project for learning pupose and as example took a kidgarden.
I have a directorry `sun` and with two apps inside it `accounts` and `equity` apps.

In accounts i have templates with login signup htmls. This section works fine without any problem.

Comment: which page you are landing on after login? Is login working as expected?

Comment: After login it goes to kids.html, however  {{stock}} does not work in kids.html    so it shows ok button but not input field. The idea is that after inserting information into field and clicking Ok button it shoud go to the garden.html page. But input field does not work

Comment: return render(request,'equity/kids.html',{'stock':stock). clising braces is missing here after stock. check if this helps.

Comment: send another variable in kids.html and check if this displaying. then you will know problem is in form or sending variable in template.

Comment: I will suggest remove garden.html from this view. calling two templates may also be a problem. use another url to redirect to garden page by taking url and using variable in urls. this will be more clean method.

Comment: Thanks I will look for your suggestions. When I do not use accounts like login signup then the two kids.html and gardens.html works good together including forms function, but when I add accounts app then it does not work. I do not why it is so.

Comment: I am not sure may be because you are 'accounts/' for two urls (accounts app and django urls.). make any of them slight different and check if this works.

Comment: I added both account urls and django url. Could you please have a look and say what is wrong withit ?

Comment: 'kids' url "path('kids/',views.TestPage.as_view(),name='kids')". this is calling TestPage in view and your logic is written in home(). change it and this will work.

Comment: call home() from accounts' view instead of TestPage from sun's.

Comment: sorry it is not clear can you please give some code, i tried to change kids to home but does not work. Woudl apprecitae if you could share some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your directory structure is still not clear. Do this. If it's works, please comment and I will explain what was wrong in your code.

in main dictionary (sun) **urls.py**, copy and paste this code.

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path,include
    from . import views
    from accounts import views as account_views # added line

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('',views.HomePage.as_view(),name='home'),
        path('accounts/',include('accounts.urls',namespace='accounts')),
        path('accounts/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
        # path('kids/',views.TestPage.as_view(),name='kids'), # comment this url
        path('kids/', account_views.home, name='kids'), # added url
        path('thanks/',views.ThanksPage.as_view(),name='thanks'),


    ]
```

**----- Edit ----**

Initially, this was URL line. `path('kids/',views.TestPage.as_view(),name='kids')`. this was calling this function:

```
class ProductDetail(models.Model):
    class TestPage(TemplateView):
        template_name = 'equity/kids.html'
```

And your logic was written in this function (views in equity app):

```
def home(request):
    stock = ChildForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        stock = ChildForm(request.POST)
        if stock.is_valid():
            data = stock.save(commit=True)
            name = data.name

            context={
            'name':name, }

        else:
            stock = ChildForm()
            return render(request,'equity/kids.html',{'stock':stock})
        return render(request,'equity/garden.html',context)


    return render(request,'equity/kids.html',{'stock':stock)
```

You had to call right function which was in equity' views. So solution was this:
replace this `path('kids/',views.TestPage.as_view(),name='kids')`

with this:

```
path('kids/', account_views.home, name='kids')
```

importing views from equity is first thing.

```
from accounts import views as account_views
```

Comment: i get this error : module 'accounts.views' has no attribute 'home'

Comment: view function you showed (1st one), is it in accounts app or in equity or in some other directory.

Comment: above i put accounts views.py

Comment: you have to call home() in which you have defined saving form and redirectiong to garden. if it's in equity, replace with this "from equity import views as account_views"

Comment: no. problem was function you were calling. Initially you were calling "TestPage" for kids url and you have defined the logic in different function (home() in this case.) you had to call home(). it does not matter where your file is (although you should keep structure clean), you have to call correct function/module.

Comment: I have edited the answer. check if helps to understand.

Comment: hey, could you please exaplain one issue. I tried to apply css style to the app however it does not work. I did the same with previous apps and it worked fine, but I do not know what is the propblem here. Maybe directory wrong or cause i double chacked and it is correct? I would appreciate if you could have a look and share your view. I put body.html and some master.css above in my code

Comment: @Nina, you can do 1) inspect in browser and check the link. if css file is opening, your link is fine. 2) clear cache in browser. sometimes updates doesn't reflectin js and css files due to cache memory. 3) if css is working in other apps, add a css property in this file for those apps (use simple property like border) to check if file is working.

Comment: i did what you said but it does not still work. I do now know what is the problem. I rechecked the directory is OK. My file is static/equity/css/master.css file. Maybe problem is here? I put it n equity app rather than in accounts . is that correct?

Comment: @Nina, can you show STATIC_URL and STATICFILES_DIRS/STATIC_ROOT. And if path is static/equity/css/master.css, your file should be on this path.

Comment: I added above everythingt i included about static files + the one in base.html where i loded static files and put reference link . Is that correct or something should be added/changed?

Comment: create a folder named "static" in base directory (that contains manage.py file). create a directory 'sun' inside 'static' and again a directory 'css' inside 'sun' directory. put your css file in 'css' folder. it will work. remember to add {% load static %} in html file. don't change any code for now. this should work. and also read about STATIC_URL and STATICFILES_DIRS.

Comment: It works cuase i wrote STATICFILES_DIR instead STATICFILES_DIRS. punctuation error.